# Spinner on Button click not responding to Click events:

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-button, onitemclicklistener

I have a spinner which drops down when a button is clicked. But when I am trying to set onItemSelectedListener, it is not taking the click events.

```
spnrLocation.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                System.out.println("location clicked" + arg2);
                edtLocation.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
                System.out.println("wfefe"
                        + parent.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: nothing in the code you can go through it.

Comment: opens means drops down.....

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this
spnrLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                System.out.println("location clicked" + i);
                edtLocation.setText(spnrLocation.getSelectedItem().toString());
                System.out.println("wfefe"
                        + spnrLocation.getSelectedItem().toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: OnItemClickListener can not be set on spinner.

Answer (score 0):

Any `View` supports the [android:clickable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aclickable) attribute (which lets you make any `View` behave like a `Button`).
There is also android:focusable.

Comment: I have used spinner.performClick(); on click event of Button