# Adjusting layout file to make the the form look better

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, android-linearlayout, android-edittext

In my application I have a form where a user enters his/her address. I have few EditTexts to enter information for city, state and postcode. I have a linear layout for the field country which gets replaced by a Country Picker. The dropdown is displayed but it stretches the Linear  Layout which makes the form look bad. I have not been able to make it look good. Sometimes the dropdown doesn't show if I make changes. Please help me as I am a beginner in building Android Apps.

Here is part of the XML file of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Rlayout_recipient"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view" android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_name" android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/addr1_hint" android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/name_hint" android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/addr_layout"
        android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/city_hint" android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
            android:layout_width="70dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/state_hint"
            android:inputType="text" android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
            android:layout_width="105dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/postcode_hint"
            android:inputType="number" android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/country_layout"
            android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addr_layout" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp" android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10" android:hint="@string/addr2_hint" android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java code for the activity:

```
public class RecipientAddressActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipient_address);        
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

    CountryPicker picker = new CountryPicker();
    picker.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    RecipientAddressActivity.this,
                    "Country Name: " + name + " - Code: " + code
                                    + " - Currency: "
                                    + CountryPicker.getCurrencyCode(code),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    transaction.replace(R.id.country_layout, picker);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Here are the links to the screenshot of how it looks

[image]

and how it is supposed to look:

[image]

Kindly, help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by replacing the linear layout with an edittext and on its click event opening the country picker.

```
edt_ctry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_ctry);
    edt_ctry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showCountryPicker();

        }
    });

protected void showCountryPicker() {
    final CountryPicker picker = CountryPicker.newInstance("Select Country");
    picker.setListener(new CountryPickerListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectCountry(String name, String code) {
            edt_ctry.setText(name);
            picker.dismiss();
        }
    });

    picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "COUNTRY_PICKER");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a linear layout with vertical orientation. I have changed some code for suite your requirements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Rlayout_recipient"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addr1_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_name"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/name_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/addr_layout"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_city"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/city_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_state"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/state_hint"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_rec_postcode"
            android:layout_width="105dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/postcode_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/country_layout"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_rec_addr2"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addr_layout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_addr1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/addr2_hint"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: With Linear Layout you cannot have android:layout_alignLeft, layout_alignRight, below, above etc. It is very difficult to position the elements as shown in the image above.

Comment: you can remove them as they wont matter in Linear Layout. Try adjusting components using weights ,gravity or layout_gravity.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using Linear Layout doesn't help, it is the same. I am wondering if I can make the country as EditText and on its touch event I open the country picker. Let me know if you have any advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: I have understood that the country picker I am using is a fragment with its own UI. This country picker replaces the linear layout(country_layout). Now I want to open this fragment as a dialog in ontouch/onclick event of an EditText probably, but I am not sure how to do it. Do you have some idea how to do it?

Comment: Better not to open spinner on edittext click as it stops taking click events. I also tried doiong the same but then had to use a dialog. You can go through this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537028/spinner-on-button-click-not-responding-to-click-events